# Single entry in list of tables using datatool + longtable

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, longtable, datatool

I'm using the `\DTLdisplaylongdb` from `datatool` in order to create a multi-page table with `longtable`. How do I provide a caption that only shows up once in the list of tables? (Right now it's showing an entry for every page of the table.)

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the `\caption{abc}` command in the heading ended by `\endfirsthead` and use a `\caption[]{...}` in the repeated heading. the [] form suppresses the writing to the toc file. (See the longtable documentation).

As @lockstep noted `datatool` hides this `longtable` feature, so you need to unhide it:-)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{dt4.csv}
40,120,40
40,90,60
35,180,20
55,190,40
40,120,40
40,90,60
35,180,20
55,190,40
40,120,40
40,90,60
35,180,20
55,190,40
40,120,40
40,90,60
35,180,20
55,190,40
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,datatool}
\textheight=12\baselineskip

\makeatletter
\def\DT@capfix{\@dtl@contcap}

\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\DT@capfix\let\@tempa\@empty\fi
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoftables

\DTLloaddb[noheader,%
keys={Temperature,Time,DT4},%
headers={\shortstack{Incubation\\Temperature},%
\shortstack{Incubation\\Time},\shortstack{Time to\\Growth}}%
]{dt4}{dt4.csv}
Now display the data in a table:

\DTLdisplaylongdb[
caption=ho hum,
shortcaption=fi fo,
contcaption=hoo ha
]{dt4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work also with `datatool`'s method to include longtables?

Comment: @lockstep looking at the datatool sources, I suspect not (which seems to be a bug) but easy to fix by patching in [] at appropriate points. If someone supplies a MWE I'll provide a patch.

Comment: I have the same problem, when i used the command endfirsthead, it also removed top line below the caption. how to handle this?

Comment: @Ahmad sorry I don't know datatool at all really, best to make a small example document and ask a new question, it is much easier with a test case, and more likely someone who knows datatool will see a new question than if you just ping me with a comment here